# Simplification of Sines and Cosines raised to a power - Fourier Series

Tags: trigonometry

I need urgent help simplifying a few sines and cosines into expressions involved sine and cosine to a maximum power of 1.

e.g. $\sin^2x = 1/2 + 1/2\cos(2x)$ - this one is easy.

$\sin^3x = \sin^2x \cdot\sin x = \sin x \cdot(1 - \cos^2x)$ = ?

$\sin^4x$ = ?

Similarly for $\cos^3x$ and $\cos^4x$.

Lastly, how would I go about doing the same for $\sin^nx$? And $\cos^nx$? Just give an idea for this last part of the question, please, not the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html)

$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2,\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

---

Alternatively, using $\displaystyle \sin3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x,\sin^3x=\frac{3\sin x-\sin3x}4$

Similarly use $\displaystyle \cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$

Using $\displaystyle\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A=2\cos^2A-1$

$$\sin^4x=\frac{(2\sin^2x)^2}4=\frac{(1-\cos2x)^2}4=\frac{1-2\cos2x+\cos^22x}4$$

Again, $\displaystyle\cos^22x=\frac{1+\cos4x}2$

Can you try the same for $\cos^4x?$

Answer (score 2):

In general, 
$$
\cos^{m-l}(x)\sin^l(x)=\Re\left[\frac{(-i)^l}{2^m}\sum_{p=0}^m\left[\sum_{q=0}^p(-1)^q\binom{m-l}{p-q}\binom{l}{q}\right](\cos((2p-m)x)+i\sin((2p-m)x))\right].
$$
If you want it slightly more explicit, you can work out different values depending on if $m$ and $l$ are even or odd.

The proof comes from the formula $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$, $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$, $e^{i(ax)}=\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax)$, and the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on lab Bhattacharjee's answer (Please give him the credit).

If you use complex Fourier series, then you just have to use Binomial theorem.

If you want to avoid a lot of algebra, let $u = e^{ix}$ and $v=e^{-ix}$. Later we will use the fact that $u v = 1$ or $v=1/u$.

Now 
$$\cos x=(u+v)/2$$

Hence
$$\cos^4 x =
1/16 (u+v)^4 = 1/16(u^4 + 4 u^3 v + 6 u^2 v^2 + 4 u v^3 + v^4) \\
=1/16 (u^4 + u^2 + 6 + v^2 + v^4)$$
Using Euler's identity again we have
$$
2 \cos 4x = (u^4 + v^4) \\
2  \cos2x = (u^2 + v^2)  
$$
So 
$$ \cos^4 x= 1/16 (2 \cos 4x +8 \cos 2x + 6)$$

If you have $\sin$ term then you need
$$
\sin x = (u-v)/(2i) \\
2i \sin 2x = u^2 - v^2\\
2i \sin 3x = u^3 -v^3
$$
etc.

So all you need is Binomial theorem and good quiet distraction free place to work.

Comment: Thank you, I was just trying out Lab Bhattacharjee's idea of using the Euler Formula, this helps!

Comment: If I wanted to do the same thing for $cos^nx$, then how could I proceed? Going by the same logic, $cos^nx = (1/2)^n * (u+v)^n$, but how would you simplify (u+v)^n?

Comment: Use Binomial theorem.