# Fourier Series of $\cos^{n}x$

Tags: calculus

I need help evaluating the integrals in Fourier Series.

For example, for the function $\cos^{2}x$, I can evaluate $a_0$, $a_n$, and $b_n$, where $a_n$ is the coefficients of the cosine terms and $b_n$ the coefficients of the sine terms. In this case, because it is an even function, only cosine terms will exist, and the integral for calculating it will become:

$$a_n=(1/2 {\pi})\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} cos^2xcosnx dx$$

How can this be solved?

Similarly, could someone please show the step-by-step calculation for the Fourier Series of $\cos^nx$?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627683/simplification-of-sines-and-cosines-raised-to-a-power-fourier-series

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\cos^{2}(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$

and

$\cos(x)\cos(y)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)\big)$

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second formula was really useful!!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: In the last formula the sign should be "+" I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered just a few minutes back. I don't know how to link to that so I copied and pasted it here. Not sure how you can give someone else the credit!

Following up on lab Bhattacharjee's answer (Please give him the credit).

If you use complex Fourier series, then you just have to use Binomial theorem.

If you want to avoid a lot of algebra, let $u = e^{ix}$ and $v=e^{-ix}$. Later we will use the fact that $u v = 1$ or $v=1/u$.

Now 
$$\cos x=(u+v)/2$$

Hence
$$\cos^4 x =
1/16 (u+v)^4 = 1/16(u^4 + 4 u^3 v + 6 u^2 v^2 + 4 u v^3 + v^4) \\
=1/16 (u^4 + u^2 + 6 + v^2 + v^4)$$
Using Euler's identity again we have
$$
2 \cos 4x = (u^4 + v^4) \\
2  \cos2x = (u^2 + v^2)  
$$
So 
$$ \cos^4 x= 1/16 (2 \cos 4x +8 \cos 2x + 6)$$

If you have $\sin$ term then you need
$$
\sin x = (u-v)/(2i) \\
2i \sin 2x = u^2 - v^2\\
2i \sin 3x = u^3 -v^3
$$
etc.

So all you need is Binomial theorem and good quiet distraction free place to work.